# optimistic locking in ServiceStack's Redis Client

Tags: redis, servicestack, optimistic-locking

We are trying to implement a pattern where we update the Redis in 2 cases
1. from the db every 5-10 minutes.
2. on specific use cases we update the current Redis data according to the use case (from time to time may need to ask the DB for the data again)

Question: What is the way to implement optimistic locking in ServiceStack's Redis?

Answer (score 0):

I'm new to Redis but have recently been reading a lot about issues like this.
I think you want WATCH with MULTI/EXEC.

The redis docs have the reference for these commands, but they're pretty minimal:

- http://redis.io/commands/watch
- http://redis.io/commands/multi
- http://redis.io/commands/exec

The "transactions" page ties them together a lot better:

- http://redis.io/topics/transactions

I also recommend the "little Redis book":

- http://openmymind.net/2012/1/23/The-Little-Redis-Book/